# Swift 3 - Declaring a simulated JSON as a response from a server

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, mapping, dao

I'm making an application with swift 3.0. But I have a problem, because in the API REST still have not implemented the service, I'm creating a simulated JSON to continue working. But the problem as you will see at the end of all the explanation in the image is that I do not know how to declare a JSON "-.- .... Basically the program will make a call to the server and it will respond with a JSON (now I pass it "the simulated" you will see it in the code). And with that JSON maps it with ObjectMapper to some models (that I pass the code) so that in the end the application has an object.

[Error declaring Simulated JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq09f.png)

These are the three models I have to map the JSON when it will come from the server or in this case, the simulated JSON.

The first is "LegendEntriesModel":

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireDomain

class LegendEntriesModel: Mappable {


fileprivate var _id_snapshot:     String?
fileprivate var _date:            String?
fileprivate var _deliverables:    [DeliverablesModel]?



init(){}

required init?(map: Map) { }

func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.id_snapshot      <- map["id_snapshot"]
    self.date             <- map["date"]
    self.deliverables     <- map["deliverables"]
}

var id_snapshot: String {
    get {
        if _id_snapshot == "" {
            _id_snapshot = ""
        }
        return _id_snapshot!
    }
    set {
        _id_snapshot = newValue
    }
}


var date: String {
    get {
        if _date == "" {
            _date = ""
        }
        return _date!
    }
    set {
        _date = newValue
    }
}


var deliverables: [DeliverablesModel] {
    get {
        if _deliverables == nil {
            _deliverables = []
        }
        return _deliverables!
    }
    set {
        _deliverables = newValue
    }
}



//MARK: RELEASE MEMORY BETWEEN OBJECT AND API REST (BROKE DEPENDENCIS)
func copy()->LegendEntriesModel {

    let legendEntriesModel  = LegendEntriesModel()

    legendEntriesModel.id_snapshot   = self.id_snapshot
    legendEntriesModel.date          = self.date
    legendEntriesModel.deliverables  = copyDeliverables()

    return legendEntriesModel
}

func copyDeliverables() -> [DeliverablesModel]{
    var newArray: [DeliverablesModel] = []
    for item in deliverables {
        newArray.append(item.copy())
    }
    return newArray
}
}
```

The second on is "DeliverablesModel"

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireDomain

class DeliverablesModel: Mappable {


fileprivate var _id:              String?
fileprivate var _type:            String?
fileprivate var _url_layer:       String?
fileprivate var _options:         OptionsDeliverablesModel?



init(){}

required init?(map: Map) { }

func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.id               <- map["id"]
    self.type             <- map["type"]
    self.url_layer        <- map["url_layer"]
    self.options          <- map["options"]
}

var id: String {
    get {
        if _id == "" {
            _id = ""
        }
        return _id!
    }
    set {
        _id = newValue
    }
}


var type: String {
    get {
        if _type == "" {
            _type = ""
        }
        return _type!
    }
    set {
        _type = newValue
    }
}


var url_layer: String {
    get {
        if _url_layer == "" {
            _url_layer = ""
        }
        return _url_layer!
    }
    set {
        _url_layer = newValue
    }
}

var options: OptionsDeliverablesModel {
    get {
        if _options == nil {
            _options = OptionsDeliverablesModel()
        }
        return _options!
    }
    set {
        _options = newValue
    }
}

//MARK: RELEASE MEMORY BETWEEN OBJECT AND API REST (BROKE DEPENDENCIS)
func copy()->DeliverablesModel {

    let deliverablesModel  = DeliverablesModel()

    deliverablesModel.id         = self.id
    deliverablesModel.type       = self.type
    deliverablesModel.url_layer  = self.url_layer
    deliverablesModel.options    = self.options

    return deliverablesModel
}
}
```

And the last one is "OptionsDeliverablesModel":

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireDomain

class OptionsDeliverablesModel: Mappable {


fileprivate var _type:                 String?
fileprivate var _max_range:            Float?
fileprivate var _min_range:            Float?
fileprivate var _title:                String?
fileprivate var _initial_max_value:    Float?
fileprivate var _initial_min_value:    Float?
fileprivate var _id:                   String?



init(){}

required init?(map: Map) { }

func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.type                       <- map["type"]
    self.max_range                  <- map["max_range"]
    self.min_range                  <- map["min_range"]
    self.title                      <- map["title"]
    self.initial_max_value          <- map["initial_max_value"]
    self.initial_min_value          <- map["initial_min_value"]
    self.id                         <- map["id"]
}

var type: String {
    get {
        if _type == "" {
            _type = ""
        }
        return _type!
    }
    set {
        _type = newValue
    }
}


var max_range: Float {
    get {
        if _max_range == 0 {
            _max_range = 0
        }
        return _max_range!
    }
    set {
        _max_range = newValue
    }
}

var min_range: Float {
    get {
        if _min_range == 0 {
            _min_range = 0
        }
        return _min_range!
    }
    set {
        _min_range = newValue
    }
}


var title: String {
    get {
        if _title == "" {
            _title = ""
        }
        return _title!
    }
    set {
        _title = newValue
    }
}

var initial_max_value: Float {
    get {
        if _initial_max_value == 0 {
            _initial_max_value = 0
        }
        return _initial_max_value!
    }
    set {
        _initial_max_value = newValue
    }
}

var initial_min_value: Float {
    get {
        if _initial_min_value == 0 {
            _initial_min_value = 0
        }
        return _initial_min_value!
    }
    set {
        _initial_min_value = newValue
    }
}

var id: String {
    get {
        if _id == "" {
            _id = ""
        }
        return _id!
    }
    set {
        _id = newValue
    }
}




//MARK: RELEASE MEMORY BETWEEN OBJECT AND API REST (BROKE DEPENDENCIS)
func copy()->OptionsDeliverablesModel {

    let optionsDeliverablesModel  = OptionsDeliverablesModel()

    optionsDeliverablesModel.type               = self.type
    optionsDeliverablesModel.max_range          = self.max_range
    optionsDeliverablesModel.min_range          = self.min_range
    optionsDeliverablesModel.title              = self.title
    optionsDeliverablesModel.initial_max_value  = self.initial_max_value
    optionsDeliverablesModel.initial_min_value  = self.initial_min_value
    optionsDeliverablesModel.id                 = self.id

    return optionsDeliverablesModel
}
}
```

With these three "Models" are what I can map the JSON inside the class DAO, but here is the problem, because I do not know how to pass my JSON that I have simulated.

The code is as follows:

```
import AlamofireDomain
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper

class DeliverablesLegendDAO : SimpleDAO {

var deliverables = Dictionary<String, Any>()

deliverables = [{"legendEntries": [{"id_snapshot": "123","date": "2016-10-20","deliveries": [{"id": "12","type": "RGB","url_layer":"topp:states","options": [{"type": "range","max_range": 100,"min_range": 0,"title": "Option RGB","initial_max_value": 100,"initial_min_value": 0,"id": "depth"}]}]}]}]

func snapshots(_ parameters: String,
           callbackFuncionOK:    @escaping (LegendEntriesModel)->(),
           callbackFunctionERROR: @escaping (Int,NSError)->()) {



    Alamofire.request(parameters,
                      method: .post,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    case 200:
                        let value = response
                        let legendEntries = Mapper<LegendEntriesModel>().map(JSONObject: value)
                        callbackFuncionOK(legendEntries!)

                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                var statusCode = -1
                if let _response = response.response {
                    statusCode = _response.statusCode
                }
                var nsError: NSError = NSError(domain: Constants.UNKNOWN_HTTP_ERROR_MSG,
                                               code: Constants.UNKNOWN_HTTP_ERROR_ID,
                                               userInfo: nil)
                if let _error = response.result.error {
                    nsError = _error as NSError
                }
                callbackFunctionERROR(statusCode,nsError)
            }

    }
}

}
```

As you can see in the image, I am declaring my simulated JSON wrong and then map it with "LegendDeliveriesModel" to an object. How can I do it?

[Error declaring simulated JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l1un.png)

If you need anything else, tell me. I repeat, the problem is in the JSON simulated statement that I do not know how to pass it to DAO and that it maps it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi not sure if you will be open to this, but it will be better to try creating a JSON in file and load it in using Bundle like this :

```
func loadJsonFrom(fileName: String) -> NSDictionary {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
    return jsonResult
}
```

Comment: I have put your function in the class itself "DeliverablesLegendDAO" (which I have attached in the code). I modified only this line. : "let path = Bundle(for: DeliverablesLegendDAO.self).path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json")" and I call it on this way "let snapshotJson = loadJsonFrom(fileNamed: "snapshotDeliveries.json")"

If I put the name of the class, it tells me that the variable path contains the value "nil". What do I have to write where it says "Class.self"?

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau hi Jordi, it depends on how you structure the class. This method returns the NSBundle object with which the specified class is associated. For your case you can just try to use path for resource if the file is placed in your project directory. I have amended my code.

Comment: Perfect !!!!!! Your solution is good !! The problem is that I need to create a JSON file for mapper my JSON. Thanks :) !!

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau you can mark my answer if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is wrong for declaring your JSON. Pretty sure declaring Dictionaries inline in swift you only use ["key":"value"]

So just remove all of the { and }

Edit: Sorry, didn't realise it was outside of a method. If you want to do that you have to declare it directly like so

```
    var deliverables = ["legendEntries": ["id_snapshot": "123","date": "2016-10-20","deliveries": ["id": "12","type": "RGB","url_layer":"topp:states","options": ["type": "range","max_range": 100,"min_range": 0,"title": "Option RGB","initial_max_value": 100,"initial_min_value": 0,"id": "depth"]]]]
```

If you're just using it as mock Data I would also consider making it a let constant rather than a variable

Comment: If I delete what you say, the same error appears in addition to an error in the AlamofireDomain :(

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it was class scope. I've updated my answer with what you need. The AlamoFire error will be something seperate.

Comment: We are advancing, Now the declaration of the variable (deliverables) is correct, you were right, it leaves without any error! But I think in the type classes "... Model" that I have attached the code, does not recognize well the "key" of the JSON. Because if I make a breakpoint (in LegendEntriesModel) in the line "self._id_snapshot <- map [" id_snapshot "]" the contents of map ["id_snapshot"] is "nil" instead of "123". And if I show a mapping of the whole mapper, it is "▿ Optional <String>
  - some: "{}" "I do not know, because those" nil "are appearing when ObjectMapper is mapping